# Default profile name in Chrome when using Watir-Webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, watir, profile, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded the Chromedriver then I extracted it to the right place (usr/bin), but I don't know what is the default profile name for the Chrome (Chromium) browser, so this line throw an error message:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => "default"
```

I tried either "current" or my username instead of "default", but none of them worked. How can I start Chrome with my default profile? Because I don't want to start a new profile without the usual preferences, and saved passwords, cookies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use chrome profile options to handle downloading files

```
download_directory = "/path/youwant/files/dowloaded/to"
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new 
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = download_directory
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "text/csv,application/pdf"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome,  :profile => profile
```

see here for more info on chromedriver profile options 
http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

Answer (score 1):

You can see you default path at `chrome://version/` url

In my case it is `/Users/mikhail/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`

For some reason proper path would be this string without last '/Default' part of the path:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

username = 'mikhail'
switches = %W[--user-data-dir=/Users/#{username}/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/]

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, switches: switches
browser.goto 'google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Chrome has that option (like Firefox has). I could not find it at http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/