# How to use a permanent profile for Chrome via Selenium Webdriver (via Waitr)

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying for a while now without luck to get little script use a permanent Chrome profile across starts.

According to the Chrome and Selenium docs the following should work:

```
driver  = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, {
  detach:  false,
  switches: ["--user-data-dir=#{ data_dir_path }"]
})

browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)
```

On first start it does initialize content in the directory given, but i'm unable to stop and start the script, as it crashes on all future starts:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok': unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426935 (820a95b0b81d33e42712f9198c215f703412e1a1),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:664:in `raw_execute'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:122:in `create_session'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:87:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:60:in `new'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:60:in `for'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
```

Next:

```
driver = ... # line from above
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: check [the answer of previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140822/default-profile-name-in-chrome-when-using-watir-webdriver)

Comment: If you are still having the problem, check out [my answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571886/webdriverexception-when-starting-chromedriver-with-user-data-dir-argument/48935483#48935483).