# WebDriverException when starting chromedriver with user-data-dir argument

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-data-dir=/path/to/profiles_dir/user_id")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", chrome_options=opts)
```

When I start Chromium for user with id = 1 it starts fine and creates a profile directory /path/to/profiles_dir/1.
Then I visit some arbitrary site and close the browser.
When I execute the above code for the second time, it throws and exception.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.4.0-112-generic x86_64)

- Chromium 64.0.3282.119 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04
- ChromeDriver 2.35
- selenium 3.8.1

I googled a lot but could not find a solution for this issue. Why can't I load the browser with the existing user profile dir? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My user-data-dir path contained a "relative" part, e.g. /path/to/my/dir/../../chromium_profiles
It seems that replacing that with a direct path, e.g /path/to/chromium_profiles fixed the error. Though I still do not understand why it could create a profile dir, but could not read it later.
After that I got a new error: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer. That was fixed by downgrading Selenium to 3.8.0 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5296

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a bug in chromedriver. I narrowed it down, and two files seem to be the culprit: `{user-data-dir}/Local State` and `{user-data-dir}/{profile-directory}/Preferences`.
If you do not specify `profile-directory`, it will be 'Default'.

Chrome/Chromium doesn't seem to be able to read these files, even if you properly close chromedriver, using `browser.quit()`.

You'll need to delete the files in order to be able to start chromedriver again, using the same profile.

I used the following code in my `finally` block, in order to delete the files:

```
if browser is not None:
    browser.quit()
    time.sleep(1)
delete_paths = ['../selenium/chrome_profile/Local State',
                '../selenium/chrome_profile/Default/Preferences']
for delete_path in delete_paths:
    if os.path.exists(delete_path):
        os.remove(delete_path)
```

Comment: were you able to reproduce the error? Does closing the browser always causes Chrome to fail reading the profile files at next startup?

Comment: Yes, unless I delete the aforementioned files, Chrome fails to read the profile at next startup. I can reproduce the error in latest ChromeDriver 2.37.

Comment: On my experience, the problem was that the `Preferences` file was blank - hence the error. So the solution is rather to check for these files to have content. And for this content to be a valid JSON. Basically, Chrome cannot read it. In my case it was due to server crash

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after mistakenly running the Google Chrome process under `root` instead of the regular user. It wrote a couple of root-owned files to the profile directory.

What helped was using `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /path/to/chrome/profile` to fix those permissions.

Change the path according to where you stored the profile.