# Browser is refusing to open because of this error : cannot parse internal JSON template

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am trying to run my tests, but this error happened unexpectedly and is not getting fixed.

<sup>org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.</sup>

```
    private WebDriver createChromeDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1280,1024");
    options.addArguments("--test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--whitelisted-ips=\"\"");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

    if (!chrome_profile_path.equals(""))
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chrome_profile_path);
    return new ChromeDriver(options);

}
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

I tried to delete Chrome Browser and reinstall it, then changed chromed driver versions, but no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException when starting chromedriver with user-data-dir argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571886/webdriverexception-when-starting-chromedriver-with-user-data-dir-argument)

Comment: Add the `code` so we can see cause

Comment: @Akzy - the code is added.